# Typescript: define type like keyof but with specific value type

Tags: typescript, types

I have interface

```
interface MyInterface {
  field1: boolean,
  field2: MyType,
  field3: MyType
}
```

and I want to create type that contains keys of this interface but only those which usage in interface gives value with type MyType. I know about existence of `keyof` but it will return ALL keys even `field1` which I don't need. So how can I get type with only `field2` and `field3`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create mapped type that checks if value extends `MyType` and if yes takes the key otherwise puts `never`, then index into it with all possible keys (to produce a union of keys that their values extend `MyType`):

```
type PickKeysOfType<T, TValue> = {
    [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends TValue ? P : never
}[keyof T];

type MyTypeKeys = PickKeysOfType<MyInterface, MyType> // "field2" | "field3"
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiAq5oF4oG8oDMD22BcUAzsAE4CWAdgOYA0UARgIYkEUCuAtvRCVAL4BuAFBDKwHpkYBjaHACSFcSUkz0QqBqxkIAGwAmARgL1cOiIwo11mzNv0AmAnESQrmrbr0BmJwiRC+EVBIKAAFMikAawBpCBBCAHlMFwgAHng6eAA1Rh02CAA+KFQ0aw0AbVCoSihIuOxMKHgAXQJ4SuaoCAAPcQo9QiacvOgAfjCoVggANx4A8rqQBqbm4SFg2T9IWPjisIiYuMTkpFT5RQlpCDpnJCKAenuoACJbT3tnqAAfF7f9L2eQA)